# Методы детекции объекта, обучающиеся на неразмеченых данных или не требующие обучения

Tags: машинное-обучение

интересует какие методы Object detection, не требующие размеченых данных существуют, помимо RCN и ее разновидностей. (требуется только bound рамка вокруг объекта, без попиксельной сегментации)

Comment: Какую задачу Вы решаете? Вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: задачу детектирования около сотни классов схожих объектов (коробок), конкретно требуется выделить объект рамкой и сделать предикт, что это за объект

Comment: Ваш комментарий неинформативный. Помимо количества классов требуется понимать природу объектов.

Comment: На текущий Ваш вопрос можно дать ответ примерно следующего рода: используйте обычную свёрточную сеть с soft-max слоем